# Shortcode within a shortcode in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am buidling real-estate website, and try to create the following:

I use a map plugin (Leaflet Map), making it possible to create maps quickly in each post (property listing) via shortcodes. The shortcode i use, is (more or less) static for every listing, only the coordinates for lat and long change from property to property. It looks like this:

```
[leaflet-map lat=36.509880 lng=-4.876681 zoom=15 zoomcontrol scrollwheel="1"]
```

I am also using ACF (advanced custom fields) plugin for WP. I use it with each listing, having fields for size, area, amount of rooms ect. I also have 2 fields, one for latitude and one for longtitude - the values from these should go directly into the above seen shortcode, resulting in a map being shown on the frontend, with the correct location of the property listing. Normally i use the following shortcode to insert a value from any of my advanced custom fields into my post/listing page:

```
[acf field="name of the custom field"]
```

But inserting the acf shortcode(s) into the leaflet map shortcode, doesn't work:

```
[leaflet-map lat=[acf field="latitude"] lng=[acf field="longtitude"] zoom=15 zoomcontrol scrollwheel="1"]
```

Can anybody help me with a solution to how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Inserted the acf shortcodes into the leaflet maps shortcode:

```
[leaflet-map lat=[acf field="latitude"] lng=[acf field="longtitude"] zoom=15 zoomcontrol scrollwheel="1"]
```

```
[leaflet-map lat=[acf field="latitude"] lng=[acf field="longtitude"] zoom=15 zoomcontrol scrollwheel="1"]
```

Comment: I don't think you can pass parameters like that. Why not use `get_field()` inside your shortcode to retrieve lat/long values instead?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I’m not on that level of phh - my knowledge is very basic - so I don’t know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: If you share the code you used to register your leaflet-map shortcode we might be able to help you out, so please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Sorry it's part of a plugin, so i don't really know where to start looking :-(

Comment: You have two options then: share the link to said plugin, or ask the plugin developer directly for help with this.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be better to use the pass the queried ACF fields into the `do_shortcode()` function.

Something along the lines of...

```
if (have_rows($field_name) :
    while (have_rows($field_name) : the_row; 
        $latitude = get_field('latitude');
        $longitude = get_field('longitude');
        do_shortcode('[leaflet-map lat=' . $latitude . ' lng=' . $longitude . ' zoom=15 zoomcontrol scrollwheel="1"]');
    endwhile;
endif;
```